# How to implement Extent report in Cucumber using EventListener and Where to find documentation for this class

Tags: automated-testing, java, test-automation-framework, cucumber

I was trying to implement a custom formatter using cucumber event listener but I was not able to get official documentation for this class.

When I Googled i got the below link :

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-core/4.7.2/cucumber/api/event/EventListener.html

But this is for version 4.7.2 , the latest Cucumber version is 6.0.0 RC2

Could someone let me know where to get class definition for cucumber 6.0.0 RC 2 , or the right way to implement reporting in cucumber ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is looking to create Test report using extent report :

Here you go :)

**TestNg runner:**

package cucumber_Runner;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

```
//Created a custom plugin
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"cucumberReport.customReportListener"},
monochrome=true,
glue={"stepDefinitions","cucumberHooks"},  //Packagename
features = {"src\\featureFiles"} //FolderName
)

public class RunnerCucumber extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    @Override
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

**And plugin class:**

```
package cucumberHooks;


import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.model.Feature;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.model.Given;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.gherkin.model.Scenario;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;
import io.cucumber.plugin.EventListener;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.EventPublisher;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.PickleStepTestStep;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestCaseStarted;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestRunFinished;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestRunStarted;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestSourceRead;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestStepFinished;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestStepStarted;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.HookTestStep;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class customReportListener implements EventListener {


    private ExtentSparkReporter spark;
    private ExtentReports extent;


    Map<String, ExtentTest> feature = new HashMap<String, ExtentTest>();
    ExtentTest scenario;
    ExtentTest step;


    public customReportListener() {
    };


    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        /*
         * :: is method reference , so this::collecTag means collectTags method in
         * 'this' instance. Here we says runStarted method accepts or listens to
         * TestRunStarted event type
         */
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestRunStarted.class, this::runStarted);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestRunFinished.class, this::runFinished);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestSourceRead.class, this::featureRead);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestCaseStarted.class, this::ScenarioStarted);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, this::stepStarted);
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepFinished.class, this::stepFinished);


    };


    /*
     * Here we set argument type as TestRunStarted if you set anything else then the
     * corresponding register shows error as it doesn't have a listner method that
     * accepts the type specified in TestRunStarted.class
     */


    // Here we create the reporter
    private void runStarted(TestRunStarted event) {
        spark = new ExtentSparkReporter("./ExtentReportResults.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        spark.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
        // Create extent report instance with spark reporter
        extent.attachReporter(spark);
    };


    // TestRunFinished event is triggered when all feature file executions are
    // completed
    private void runFinished(TestRunFinished event) {
        extent.flush();
    };


    // This event is triggered when feature file is read
    // here we create the feature node
    private void featureRead(TestSourceRead event) {
        String featureSource = event.getUri().toString();
        String featureName = featureSource.split(".*/")[1];


        if (feature.get(featureSource) == null) {


            feature.putIfAbsent(featureSource, extent.createTest(featureName));
        }
    };


    // This event is triggered when Test Case is started
    // here we create the scenario node
    private void ScenarioStarted(TestCaseStarted event) {
        String featureName = event.getTestCase().getUri().toString();


        scenario = feature.get(featureName).createNode(event.getTestCase().getName());
    };


    // step started event
    // here we creates the test node
    private void stepStarted(TestStepStarted event) {


        String stepName = " ";
        String keyword = "Triggered the hook :";


        // We checks whether the event is from a hook or step
        if (event.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
            // TestStepStarted event implements PickleStepTestStep interface
            // WHich have additional methods to interact with the event object
            // So we have to cast TestCase object to get those methods
            PickleStepTestStep steps = (PickleStepTestStep) event.getTestStep();
            stepName = steps.getStep().getText();
            keyword = steps.getStep().getKeyword();


        } else {
            // Same with HoojTestStep
            HookTestStep hoo = (HookTestStep) event.getTestStep();
            stepName = hoo.getHookType().name();
        }


        step = scenario.createNode(Given.class, keyword + " " + stepName);
    };


    // This is triggered when TestStep is finished
    private void stepFinished(TestStepFinished event) {


        if (event.getResult().getStatus().toString() == "PASSED") {
            step.log(Status.PASS, "This passed");


        } else if (event.getResult().getStatus().toString() == "SKIPPED")


        {


            step.log(Status.SKIP, "This step was skipped ");
        } else {
            step.log(Status.FAIL, "This failed");
        }
    };


}
```

**Maven**

```
<dependencies>
<! —  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports →


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
<! —  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng →


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
<! —  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java →


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
<! —  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander →


    <! — https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng →
<! —  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander →


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>24.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
<! —  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng →


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
<! —  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java →


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Output:**

[image]