# I am trying to implement Extent Report in Cucumber project with Cucumber Event Publisher class but getting exception

Tags: cucumber, extent

I am trying to create Extent Report in cucumber project with EventPublisher class. Basically took help from
[How to implement Extent report in Cucumber using EventListener and Where to find documentation for this class](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44536/how-to-implement-extent-report-in-cucumber-using-eventlistener-and-where-to-find)

But when I am running the project, I am getting below exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.npc.qa.listeners.customReportListener.stepFinished(customReportListener.java:130)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.sendAll(AbstractEventPublisher.java:36)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.CanonicalOrderEventPublisher.handle(CanonicalOrderEventPublisher.java:18)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:44)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:12)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.emitTestRunFinished(CucumberExecutionContext.java:107)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.finishTestRun(CucumberExecutionContext.java:88)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.finish(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:125)
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.tearDownClass(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:53)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
... Removed 29 stack frames
```

Comment: Please add the code where you get that exception

Answer (score 1):

If you check the error , the exception is thrown at
com.npc.qa.listeners.customReportListener.stepFinished(customReportListener.java:130)

So check the customreporter class line 130 , the issue is caused  when you try to access driver object in listner class after it is destroyed.

Unlike , testNG listner class cucumber uses an event class so it just gets the event and process In the order of Queue . It doesn't stop the code execution  and so you won't be able to access the driver object inside that,as the state of driver keeps on changing as the code is still executing